# How to launch Plan app with iOS 6

Tags: ios6

How I can launch the new iOS 6 Plan application?

With previous iOS I use :

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[app openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=%f,%f",self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude,self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude]]];
```

Someone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean maps application. You should change the **maps.google.com** part with **maps.apple.com**